# How to implement a recursive process in R?

Tags: r, recursion

Say I have a vector `v = c(250,1200,700)`, a starting value `n` and a function e.g.

```
f = function(v){

g = function(v){ 
    cases(
    v <= 20 -> 0.1,
    v > 20 & v <= 100 -> 0.075,
    v > 100 -> .05
    )  
  }
  suppressWarnings(g(v))
}
```

`f` is written using `cases` from the `memisc` package - I'm still new to R and would be keen to hear if `f` can be coded in a 'better' way. Anyway, I am looking for code that will perform the following recursive process (including for vectors of a 'large' length):

```
f(n), 
f(n)*v[1]+n, 
f(f(n)*v[1]+n)*v[2] + f(n)*v[1]+n, 
f(f(f(n)*v[1]+n)*v[2] + f(n)*v[1]+n)*v[3] + f(f(n)*v[1]+n)*v[2] + f(n)*v[1]+n
```

Ultimately I am interested in the value of the last line.

Cheers for any help

Comment: Perhaps I'm being dense this morning (no coffee), but I don't see an explanation of how your function 'f' is related to your recursive process.  Is the function 'A' supposed to be replaced with your function 'f', or does `A(n)` represent `f(v[n])`?  Would you mind providing a little more detail?

Comment: Also, did you mean `v > 20 & v <= 100`, rather than `w <= 100`?

Comment: sorry it's me that was being dense! I'll change it all now

Comment: Sure the first step if `f(n)` and not just `n`? it would be more logic to me, as the process would be decribed then as `x[i+1] = f(x[i])*v[i] + x[i]` for i>1.

Comment: Joris Meys has described it more clearly than myself (first paragraph)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you right, this is the process you're talking about:

```
 X1 = f(n)
 X2 = X1*v[1] + n
 X3 = F(X2)*v[2] + X2
 X4 = F(X3)*v[3] + X3 
...
```

If you need all in-between steps, a recursive function is rather useless as you need the in-between steps stored in the result as well. So you can easily code that using basic R :

```
Thefun <- function(v,n){
  l <- length(v)
  res <- numeric(l+1)

  res[1] <- g(n)
  res[2] <- res[1]*v[1] + n
  for(i in seq(2,l)){
    res[i+1] <- res[i] + g(res[i])*v[i]
  }
  return(res)
}
```

The last value of the result is the result you need. As you only needed the result of the last step, you can do it recursively using `Recall`:

```
Recfunc <- function(v,n){
    l <- length(v)
    if(l > 0){
        res <- Recall(v[-l],n)
        return(g(res)*v[l] + res)
    } else {
      return(n)
    } 
}
```

---

On a sidenote

You can define your function g different, like this (I call it fv) :

```
fv <- function(v){
   0.1*(v <= 20) + 0.075*(v > 20 & v <=100) + 0.05*(v>100)
}
```

If compared to your function, you gain a 6 fold increase in speed.

```
vec <- sample(1:150,1e5,TRUE)
benchmark(
   fv(vec),
   g(vec),
   columns=c("test","replications","elapsed","relative"),
   replications = 1000

)

     test replications elapsed relative
1 fv(vec)         1000    9.39    1.000
2  g(vec)         1000   56.30    5.996
```

Comment: You write the recursrion like me . But What do you get for n=10 and v of size 3 for example? +1 for the Recall(I don't know this one).

Comment: @agstudy the values `0.1   35   125   160`, so as OP is interested in the final result ultimately, it's `160`.

Comment: You can speed it up slightly more by performing one less logical comparison: `(.v <= 20) * 0.1 + (.v > 20) * 0.075 - (.v > 100) * 0.025`

Comment: thanks Joris Meys, both for the answer and the side note. I haven't come across `Recall` before. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I assume here that `n` is  length of v.
I rewrite the recusrion like this :

```
y1 <- n                  ## slight change here
y2 <- f(y1)*v[1] +y1, 
y3 <- f(y2)*v[2] +y2
y4 <- f(y3)*v[3] +y3
.... I can''t see the terms > length(v) so my first assumption
```

So for example you can implement this like :

```
filter.f <- function(func=f,coef=v){
  n <-  length(coef)
  y <- numeric(n)
  y[1] <- n
  for(i in 2:n)
    y[i] <- func(y[i-1])*coef[i-1]+y[i-1] ## here the recursion
  y[1] <- f(n)
  y
}

 filter.f()
[1]   0.1 124.0 159.0 191.5
 v=c(250, 1200, 700)
filter.f()
[1]   0.1  28.0 118.0
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be, in contrary. It's a value that could or could not be part of v.

Comment: @JorisMeys yes. I can't right the recursion for terms > length(v).. see my edit please.

Comment: I don't think the math is right here.  For `v=c(250, 1200, 700)`, it looks like the values should be: `0.1 27 118`.

Comment: @agstudy n is a staring value that is chosen, so your function should take that one into account as well. See my answer.

Comment: @Dinre, Without specifying `n`, you can't do the math. Say n=3 (what both of you assume), the result is `0.1  28  118  153`.

Comment: I don't think the 'n' is fixed.  I assume each line is a new 'n', where `n=1:3`

Comment: @Dinre: the phrase "a starting value `n`" says "value", not "vector", and definitely not "indices of vector v".